# Equation to find angle in right triangle if you know two sides.

Tags: geometry

So for example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbZxO.jpg you have right triangle and you know it’s catheters and I need to find this angle. Helm me out with the equation!

Comment: $\tan^{-1}(y/x)$. You should look at trigonometry equations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Compute $$\tan(\alpha)=\frac{y}{x}$$

Answer (score 0):

For this question, we will use $\tan$ because we know the sides $x$ and $y$, which are the opposite and adjacent sides of the angle.

$\tan (\theta) =$ $o \over a$ (Opposite over adjacent) The opposite side of the angle is $y$, and the adjacent side is $x$.

$\tan (\theta) =$$y \over x$

$\theta = \tan^{-1}($$y \over x$$)$